# Can I wrap sessions to create a transaction with slick?

Tags: postgresql, scala, transactions, slick

I have my DAO code that looks like:

UserDao.scala:

```
def save(user: User)(implicit session: Session) ... {
   ....
}
```

Then UserService:

```
def save(user: User) .. {
  db.withSession { implicit session =>
      userDao.save(user)
   }
}
```

I have other ABCService classes that have the exact same pattern for my other models.

Now my question is, now I want to create a transaction around multiple calls, is this possible?

OtherService:

```
   userService.save(user)
   accountService.save(account)
```

Now if either of those calls fail, I want it to rollback.  The problem is the sessions are handled indepentaley currently in each Service class, so if the userService.save(user) passes but accountService.save fails, *I have data that is in a bad state.*

**How can I solve this problem?**

Answer (score 7):

Slick has `withTransaction` that will work exactly the same as `withSession`, except that everything is executed within a transaction.

Require the signatures of your service functions to have an `implicit: Session` parameter (if they're to be used within a transaction), and remove the provisioned `Session` from within them:

```
def save(user: User)(implicit: Session) {
    userDao.save(user)
}
```

Then provide that `Session` via `withTransaction`:

```
db.withTransaction{ implicit session =>
     userService.save(user)
     accountService.save(account)
}
```

Comment: Ok, so basically moving the session blocks up one level from the Dao to the service layer right?

Comment: Yes, if that's where the transaction needs to start and end.

Comment: The problem is both userService.save and accountService.save already have this db.withSession block.  If I remove it, then I have to wrap each call with db.withSession in my controller actions.  Get what I am saying?  I was wrong, all my session code is already in the session layer.

Comment: I know what you're saying, but that's really the only way you're going to get multiple functions from different services into a transaction. If you're not going to be using many transactions, perhaps have `save(user: User)(implicit session: Session)` and `saveWithSession(user: User)`.

Comment: I guess I am used to hibernate where I believe it handled if you put multiple blocks of session/transactions in a hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could give a look at https://github.com/tim-group/scalaquery_nested

Their implementation looks very concise: https://github.com/tim-group/scalaquery_nested/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/timgroup/scalaquery_nested/NestedScalaQuerySessionsAndTransactions.scala

But they use exception to detect wrapped session, not sure whether it has performance issue for complicated session/transaction nesting..